# Attributed string with text attachment and truncation

Tags: objective-c, nsattributedstring, nstextattachment

I've got an attributed string with an image attached (`NSTextAttachment`). This works alright, but I've got a problem with truncation that I can't seem to solve.

In the example, suppose the string `##` is the image. So my string looks something like `Hello world! ##`. Tail truncation is set on the paragraph style.

Now, if the space is constrained, the text is truncated with ellipsis (which is what I want). But unfortunately the image is truncated as well.

So the result is something like:

```
Hello w...
```

but I'd like it to look like:

```
Hello...##
```

That is, I want the image attachment to not get truncated, it should always be visible.

The reason for the attachment is that I want the image to always be at the end of the string, so when the text is short the image is at the end and when the text wraps to multiple lines I also want the image to be at the end. Trying to manually position the image "on the outside" wouldn't work as the text then wouldn't get truncated correctly.

So, is there a way to tell `NSAttributedString` not to truncate the image?

Example code that produces the attributed string:

```
NSString *title;
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString;
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraph;
NSDictionary *attributes;
NSTextAttachment *attachment;

paragraph = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
paragraph.hyphenationFactor = 1.0;
paragraph.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;

attributes = @{
    NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [self titleTextColor],
    NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paragraph,
};

title = @"Hello world!";
attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:title
                                                          attributes:attributes];

attachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
attachment.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"];
[attributedString appendAttributedString:[NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:attachment]];
[attachment release];

self.titleLabel.attributedText = attributedString;

[attributedString release];
[paragraph release];
```

**Edit:** A vital part of this (which gets lost in the description above a bit) is that this solution needs to work for multiline texts.

Answer (score 4):

I do not think that you get the desired results with "tricks". You have to do the real work: Subclass [`NSTextContainer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSTextContainer_Class_TextKit/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013281) and overwrite [`-lineFragmentRectForProposedRect:atIndex:writingDirection:remainingRect:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSTextContainer_Class_TextKit/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTextContainer/lineFragmentRectForProposedRect%3aatIndex%3awritingDirection%3aremainingRect%3a). That includes setting up your own text stack.

The code is too long to be posted here. But there are some samples in documentation. (The documentation of OS X is richer, IIRC. There are differences, but you can use it for a basic understanding of the parts.) So this answer is still a pointer.

As you are living in Munich, I assume that you understand german. Therefore I want to mention that there is a code sample in the second part of my book, chapter 6, for a view that layouts text around a hole in the middle. You can do the same by sparing out a rect at the end.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Could elaborate a bit on this? I've done some experiments with NSTextContainer and I can't even get it to track the end of a multi-line string. So what would I do in the overridden `lineFragmentRectForProposedRect:atIndex:writingDirection:remainingRect:`?

Comment: My basic idea is that when you reach the end of the text and see that it does not fit into the proposed rect, you simply subtract the space for the image at the right side (assuming left-to-right writing direction) to make the text system shorten the string. Than you draw the image at the right side. If there is enough space, you know the last position used by the text and draw the image there.

Comment: To recognize the end of the string, characterIndex should help. Maybe you have to calculate the layout of the next characters starting from character index to see, whether it fits.

Comment: Good idea. So far, this looks like the most precise solution: let it draw normally if possible, provide a shortened last line to correctly draw the ellipsis and then manually draw the image. I'll play around with this today or tomorrow.

Comment: After playing around with this for well over an hour, I can't get it to do what I want. It's already a problem to have NSTextStorage  draw 2 lines and truncate the last. `drawWithRect:options:context:` ignores the values from the text container, and letting the layout manager draw the glyphs always draws the whole string without truncating. Oh dear…

Comment: What do you mean with "`drawWithRect:…` ignores it"? I think `lineFragment…` is sent inside the base implementation of `drawWithRect:…` So you cannot overwrite it. Shall I give you an OS X project for the basic structure?

Comment: With "ignores it" I meant that my NSTextContainer implementation gets called but the returned CGRects are not adhered to (e.g. I've changed the positions and that works when using the NSLayoutManager to draw the string, but when I call `drawWithRect:` on the very same NSTextStorage the NSTextContainer is called but the result is ignored. I'd appreciate if you could send me some code, my e-mail is listed on my user page. Thanks a lot!

Comment: E-Mail is on the way. Why do you "call" `drawWithRect:…`? You should never do it …

Comment: I did not find your e-mail address?!

Comment: Try to download it from here: http://cocoading.de/webspace/layoutstack%203%2010.9.zip (Download immediately starts)

Comment: I was busy at work and now I'm ill and can't think, so I couldn't make any progress here. Since the bounty is about to expire and you've made the biggest effort I'll award you the bounty. If I can make it work, I'll post it as an answer myself and will accept that.

Answer (score 3):

This is not easily achievable. You could set the paragraph style to `NSLineBreakByTruncatingMiddle`, but then the result would be that the last line is truncated in the middle (`"Hel...rld!##"`)

So you have a few options.

- You could redesign so that the image isn't placed at the end of the text.
- You could calculate yourself the end of string, truncate it and add the text attachment - not simple to do.
- Use iOS7's Text Kit to implement a custom truncation logic. Unfortunately, despite what has been written erroneously on many blogs and Apple's own documentation, `UILabel` does not use TextKit to render text, it uses CoreText, thus making things a little harder. I would recommend dropping the `UILabel` entirely and going with a custom `UIView` implementation with Text Kit backing. You can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19471940/983912) a small example of a view drawing text using Text Kit, resulting in a view similar to a label. Now you can get bounding boxes of the drawn glyphs, and place the image correctly.

Neither option is perfect. You have not mentioned what the image is and why you need it at the end of the last line. I would probably go with option #1 and change the design a little, although the Text Kit option is not that difficult to implement.

Comment: If I have to, CoreText might be a solution but it's a lot of work (and [needs extra work for the image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899178/how-to-draw-images-among-rich-text-with-coretext-ios)). I don't care implementing my own `UIView` for this but I'm looking for the "most sane" solution.

Comment: @DarkDust You are describing a difficult case. I don't think "TextKit" is insane, just that apple got lazy and didn't finish the work to use it in labels. Could be that Apple's controls still have bugs with TextKit, so they left the labels with CT directly. Labels used to use WebKit; at least that is an improvement. >_<

Answer (score 1):

Recently I also faced a similar situation and this is the solution I ended up and it is working really good in my case.

I had a UILabel and I wanted to display a string with an image followed by. But if this composition exceeds the UILabel width, I had to truncate the string and then append the image at the end.

I will post my solution below and it will be helpful to someone.

```
  /// Provide a single line attibuted string with the image at the end of the string, and will truncate the string if the whole composision will exceed the frame size.
  /// - Parameters:
  ///   - string: The string which we are going to append the image
  ///   - rect: The UILabel rect of the string
  ///   - font: The Font to use in the attributed string
  ///   - imageName: The image name
  ///   - imageOrigin: The image location
  /// - Returns: The attibuted string with the image at the end. This string will be truncated if needed.
  private func getAttributedStringWithImage(string: String,
                                            rect: CGSize,
                                            font: UIFont,
                                            imageName: String,
                                            imageOrigin: CGPoint) -> NSAttributedString {
    
    // creating image to append at the end of the string
    let iconImage = UIImage(named: imageName)!
    let icon = NSTextAttachment()
    icon.bounds = CGRect(x: imageOrigin.x, y: imageOrigin.y, width: iconImage.size.width, height: iconImage.size.height)
    icon.image = iconImage
    let iconString = NSAttributedString(attachment: icon)
    
    // we will calculate the "attributed string length with image at the end" to deside whether we need to truncate
    // the string to append the image or not by looping the string
    var newStr = ""
    for char in string {
      newStr += String(char)
      
      let attStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: (newStr + "..."), attributes: [ .font: font, .kern: 0.0 ])
      let stringRect = attStr.boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: rect.height),
                                           options: [.usesLineFragmentOrigin, .usesFontLeading], context: nil)
      
      if stringRect.width + imageOrigin.x +  iconImage.size.width + 5 > rect.width {
        newStr += "..."
        break
      }
    }
    
    let titleString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: newStr, attributes: [ .font: font, .kern: 0.0 ])
    titleString.append(iconString)
    
    return titleString
  }
```

And call it like this:

```
  let attributedText = getAttributedStringWithImage(string: contactEmailOrNumber,
                                                    rect: self.titleLabel.frame.size,
                                                    font: UIFont(name: "FontName-Bold", size: xx.0)!,
                                                    imageName: "ImageName",
                                                    imageOrigin: CGPoint(x: 6, y: -3))
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess an approach would be to get the length of the full string, the length of the truncated string, then generate a new NSString with `Hello world!`, truncate the difference + 3, then add `...##` at the end.

Would it fit your purpose?

Comment: For a one-line string something like this could work, yes. Unfortunately I need it to work multi-line strings.

Answer (score 0):

When you display it in the UILabel did you set

```
self.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingMiddle
```

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't do what I want at all. The output is totally different.