# CoreText Attributed String Height Calculation Inaccurate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, core-text

CoreText isn't giving the correct height of the attributed string (its short by a line or more). I have seen a lot of posts on SO about this but unable to understand or find a solution. Can somebody explain how Core Text height calculation works? Here's an example code I wrote showing inaccurate height calculation.

**Context**

I have a collection view where the cell's height is determined by the content inside it.
I am displaying paragraphs of text in the cells. I would like to save some performance by doing the height calculation using core text. I have seen that with core text's height calculation I could save  ~300ms.

**Code**

// Height Calculation

```
+ (CGFloat)getHeight
{
    NSString *text = @"The Apple HIG recommends to use a common color for links and buttons and we did just that. By using the same color throughout the app we trained the user to always associate blue to a link.The Apple HIG recommends to use a common color for links and buttons and we did just that.By using the same color throughout the app we trained the user to always associate blue to a link.";

    NSAttributedString *attrStr = [self attributedString:text withLinespacing:3 withLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

    CTFramesetterRef frameSetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((__bridge CFAttributedStringRef)(attrStr));
    CGSize suggestedSize = CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints(frameSetter,
                                                                    CFRangeMake(0, attrStr.length),
                                                                    NULL,
                                                                    CGSizeMake(320, 9999),
                                                                    NULL);

    return suggestedSize.height;
}
```

// Load the same text when Cell is about to display

```
- (void)loadData
{
    NSString *text = @"The Apple HIG recommends to use a common color for links and buttons and we did just that.By using the same color throughout the app we trained the user to always associate blue to a link.The Apple HIG recommends to use a common color for links and buttons and we did just that.By using the same color throughout the app we trained the user to always associate blue to a link.";

    NSAttributedString *attrStr = [[self class] attributedString:text withLinespacing:3 withLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

    // UILabel element
    self.textLabel.attributedText = attrStr;

    self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
    self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
}
```

// Generate attributed string with leading, font and linebreak

```
+ (NSAttributedString *)attributedString:(NSString *)string
                        withLinespacing:(CGFloat)linespacing
                      withLineBreakMode:(NSLineBreakMode)lineBreakMode
{
    NSMutableAttributedString *attrStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string];
    NSInteger strLength = [string length];
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *style = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    style.lineSpacing = linespacing;
    style.lineBreakMode = lineBreakMode;

    [attrStr addAttributes:@{NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: style,
                         NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:15]} range:NSMakeRange(0, strLength)];

    return attrStr;
}
```

The above code uses core text to calculate the height and UILabel to display the text. The UILabel has 3 constraints to the cell **{Top:17, Leading:13px, Trailing:13px}**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints` is known to be buggy, returning incorrect height values. The missing line bug you experience is very common, and there are no good solutions that I know of, only ugly workarounds which never give 100% accurate results.

For iOS7 and above, I recommend moving to TextKit. Somehow the calculations performed there internally do work correctly, while being based on Core Text also. Using `NSLayoutManager`'s `usedRectForTextContainer:` returns a correct result.

You can see a more complete answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19471940/983912). While not exactly 100% on topic, there is some discussion about the bugginess of Core Text calculations.

Comment: Thanks for the TextKit tip. I need to calculate the height before rendering so I am using `boundingRectForGlyphRange:` for height calculation. Is it possible to use UILabel for rendering (instead of `drawGlyphsForGlyphRange:`)? With UILabel and auto-layout, the label's height is short of cell's height for some reason.

Comment: @Praveen It is possible, yes. Are you sure you have setup constraints correctly? If you are letting the label resize by the way of content compression resistance and content hugging, remember to set the `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` property of the label to the bounding width of the superview (in `layoutSubviews`, before calling the super implementation).

Comment: I am looking into my constraints but don't see my mistake yet. I have only one UILabel inside a UICollectionViewCell with TopSpace:17, Leading and Trailing space of 13. So essentially the max width can only be 294 for the iPhone. Content compression is 750 and Content hugging is 251 for the label. I have also set the preferredMaxLayoutWidth to be 294 before I call super in layoutSubViews. The width of the label after calling super is indeed 294 as expected.

Comment: @Praveen Set content compression resistance and hugging to 1000 as well.